# Entity Framework 5 and Oracle: Expression with closure affecting performance when querying against a non-unique indexed field

Tags: performance, oracle, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I have a performance issue with Entity Framework 5 and Oracle DB.

I have a simple SQL select: `SELECT * FROM NOTE WHERE NOTENUMBER = '1A23456'`

`NOTENUMBER` is included in an index on a table called NOTE, but the field is NOT primary key / unique.

- When I execute the statement with Oracle SQL Developer, results return
  quickly and query plan shows that RANGE SCAN is being used like it
  should.
- When I use Entity Framework, the generated SQL takes a lot
  longer (5 seconds vs. 30ms).
- When I use Entity Framework and query
  with a **primary key field** (NOTE_KEY), results return as quickly as with SQL 
  Developer.

I suspect 2 things:

- There's some problem with EF and Oracle.DataAccess-provider not using the non-unique-index that is available. It would help if I had debug symbols for Entity Framework 5, but I can't find them anywhere.
- The performance problem is somewhere in EF, regarding closures and/or the way I use generic repository pattern with EF:

  If I call my repository like this:
  `var notenumber = "1A23456";`
  `var notes = repository.All(n => n.NOTENUMBER == notenumber).ToList();`
  The predicate comes in at the method `All` as:
  `{n => (n.NOTE == value(Tester.Program+<>c__DisplayClass0).notenumber)}`
  And EfProf-profiler traces the resulting SQL as:

  `SELECT "Extent1"."NOTE_KEY"      AS "NOTE_KEY",`
  `"Extent1"."NOTENUMBER"    AS "NOTENUMBER",`
  `"Extent1"."NOTETEXT"      AS "NOTETEXT",`
  `FROM   "NOTE_DBA"."NOTE" "Extent1"`
  `WHERE  ("Extent1"."NOTENUMBER" = '1PSA0500237500' /* @p__linq__0 */)`

  And the query takes takes **~5500ms**.

  On the other hand, if I call my repository like this:
  `var notes = repository.All(n => n.NOTENUMBER == "1A23456").ToList();`
  Then the predicate comes in as:
  `{n => (n.NOTENUMBER == "1A23456")}`
  And EfProf-profiler traces the resulting SQL as:

  `SELECT "Extent1"."NOTE_KEY"      AS "NOTE_KEY",`
  `"Extent1"."NOTENUMBER"    AS "NOTENUMBER",`
  `"Extent1"."NOTETEXT"      AS "NOTETEXT",`
  `FROM   "NOTE_DBA"."NOTE" "Extent1"`
  `WHERE  ('1PSA0500237500' = "Extent1"."NOTENUMBER")`

  And the query takes **~30ms**.

  So the only difference is the order of the condition in the WHERE-clause, and the fact that in the latter there seems to be no parameter replaced by EF

I use VS2010 and .NET4, and reference EF5 (v4.4.0.0).
The repository's All-method is:

```
public IQueryable<NOTE> All(Expression<Func<NOTE, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    var setOfNotes = GetDbSet<NOTE>();
    var notesQuery = from note in setOfNotes select note;
    if (predicate != null)
    {
        notesQuery = notesQuery.Where(predicate);
    }
    return notesQuery;
}
```

I tried to create a CompiledQuery, I tried using `setOfNotes.AsNoTracking()` and I tried to target .NET 4.5 - with no difference in performance.

One way I was able to get this particular query fast, was to use Oracle's basic Data Provider for .NET (ODB.NET) and construct the query manually, but I'd rather not stick with that solution. Again, if I use a primary field in the where clause, the query is fast even with EF and the same All-method.

So the problem seems to be somewhere in EF. I feel could find out a lot more if I only had the symbols for EntityFramework.dll.

Could there be a problem with the way EF invokes predicates? How does the '@p_*linq*_0'-parameter get replaced inside EF?

Comment: Look at the SQL which EF executed. That way you can test your hypotheses.

Comment: I used Ef Profiler for that. The only difference is that there seems to be no parameteres that are replaced(?) in the second case where predicate has the value of NOTENUMBER. Parameters meaning /* @p__linq__0 */

Comment: Ok I didn't see the SQL in your post. EF works as it should (using parameters). I don't know anything about Oracle so I'm out.

Comment: You'll need to find the entire SQL statement which is executed, edit your post, and include it, along with the definition of the table and the indexes which exist on your table.  Without those things there's really not much anyone can do to help you as we've got no idea what's really going on.

Comment: I've included the traced SQL from Entity Framework Profiler. The only difference is in the WHERE-clause.

Comment: "So the problem seems to be somewhere in EF." -- Really? It looks more like an Oracle problem to me. A where clause on an indexed field should use that field's index even if a parameter is used, should it not? You can try with a plain old `DataSet` and directly entering the SQL to use. I expect it to be equally slow if you enter `SELECT ... WHERE "NOTENUMBER" = @NoteNumber`.

Comment: Well, using ODB.NET's OracleDataReader it's not equally slow. I tried the same query 100 times in a row and it took ~45ms on average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem. The reason why the index wasn't used in my case was that I was passing a string (unicode) from .NET as parameter. This was compared with a non-unicode database field.

The solution was to convert the string parameter to non-unicode before passing it in the where clause:

```
using System.Data.Objects;

EntityFunctions.AsNonUnicode( myUnicodeParam)
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out what SQL Entity Framework has generated use the ToTraceString method, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring.aspx

It may be that the NOTE table has relationships, and eager loading is turned on. In that case the EF generated SQL would try and load all the related data.

Comment: I used Entity Framework profiler for tracing the SQL and edited the post to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few bugs and design issues in the code.

First, the custom "All" method. The line of code that selects all notes into notesQuery does nothing at all.

```
var notesQuery = from note in setOfNotes select note;
```

Remember that 'setOfNotes' is already an IQueryable of type Note. The statement effectively says "Select all notes from select all notes". LINQ will completely remove this statement internally (with a slight performance cost), so it can be safely removed from your code.

Try changing the function to:

```
public IQueryable<NOTE> All(Expression<Func<NOTE, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    var setOfNotes = GetDbSet<NOTE>();
    return (predicate == null) ? setOfNotes : setOfNotes.Where(predicate);
}
```

There are larger, fundamental problems in the design. For .NET collections, the method "All" is used to determine whether an predicate is true for every element in the set. It doesn't mean "return all items". Granted, you're creating your own repository, but the naming conflicts with standard .NET usage. I'd actually suggest you get rid of your custom repository altogether.

LINQ is "language integrated query" - the whole point is to have it *integrated* with your code. Wrapping another layer around it is pointless, and counter intuitive. DbSet implements the IQueryable interface - expose that directly and query it in your code. It allows LINQ to cache queries more efficiently and avoids redundancy. IQueryable already *is* is repository, no point creating another one. You just threw away the power of LINQ and dropped back to the days of stored procedures.

If you have complex queries used in multiple locations, just write an extension method on IQueryable that returns another IQueryable. Then you can GetDbSet().SliceAndDice()!

Back to your original problem, you might be mixing assignment with comparison. The code you pasted included:

```
var notes = repository.All(n => n.NOTENUMBER = notenumber).ToList();
```

Which is incorrect, its trying to assign 'notenumber' to the n.NOTENUMBER property, not testing equality. Perhaps it was just a typo in the stack overflow post. Instead, try:

```
var notes = repository.All(n => n.NOTENUMBER == notenumber).ToList();
```

Or even better:

```
var notes = GetDbSet<NOTE>().Where(n => n.NOTENUMBER == notenumber).ToList();
```

I suspect the equality bug was just a typo, but the problem likely lies in the way you're "layering" a custom repository over an IQueryable repository and passing an expression between them and is mucking up EF's ability to cache properly.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The method all is actually translated both in signature and in its contents for simplicity's sake. There are additional conditions in notesQuery, I just wanted to show it as clear as possible. And yep, the assignment is a typo also. I'll still try with the DbSet itself, but I can't replace my generic repository since I have so many sources that I query in other places in my application. I use a modified version of this generic repository pattern: http://kazimanzurrashid.com/posts/entity-framework-code-first-bootstrapping

Comment: I still think its pointless creating a repository for what is already a repository. I see a lot of other sample code like that, and it makes me cringe. Layers and layers and layers of abstraction with no benefit!